# Mysql multiple addwithvalue: one returned value is enough

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

I have a query that has multiple addwithvalue values

```
        IDCheck.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cloudposgebruikers WHERE id = @id AND licentie1hc = @lc1 AND licentie2hc = @lc2"
        + " AND licentie3hc = @lc3 AND licentie4hc = @lc4 AND licentie5hc = @lc5 AND licentie6hc = @lc6 AND licentie7hc = @LC7 AND licentie8hc = @lc8"
        + " AND licentie9hc = @lc9 AND licentie10hc = @lc10";
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", licenseid);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("lc1", GetId);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("lc2", GetId);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("lc3", GetId);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("lc4", GetId);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("lc5", GetId);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("lc6", GetId);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("lc7", GetId);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("lc8", GetId);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("lc9", GetId);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("lc10", GetId);
```

Of course, this will compare ALL these values and only return true if all values are present

Let's say only "licentie5hc" and "id" matches => return true

or let's say only "id" and licentie1hc" matches.. => return true

is this possible ? I know i can use different query's but i just need "id" and one of the "licentie x hc" parameters to match...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IDCheck.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cloudposgebruikers 
    WHERE id = @id AND (licentie1hc = @lc1 OR licentie2hc = @lc2 
        OR licentie3hc = @lc3 OR licentie4hc = @lc4 OR licentie5hc = @lc5 
        OR licentie6hc = @lc6 OR licentie7hc = @LC7 OR 
        licentie8hc = @lc8 OR licentie9hc = @lc9 OR licentie10hc = @lc10)";
```

which equates to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE id=@id AND(lic1=@lic1 OR lic2=@lic2...etc...OR lic10=@lc10);
```

NOTE: I understand that you probably cannot change your database structure, but having ten columns as you do, indicates that your database could benefit from some refactoring.

Comment: If i had rep enough i'd gave you a +1 for the quick and good answer.. Thanks !!

Comment: thx! Check out rs answer, he caught something that I didn't to greatly simplify your code.

Comment: Hehe no we can't change our db structure, it's part of our licensing system so there's no other option.. But thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 2):

Change your query to use OR instead of AND and you don't have to use different parameters for same value,try this,

```
IDCheck.CommORText = "SELECT * FROM cloudposgebruikers WHERE id = @id OR licentie1hc = @lc OR licentie2hc = @lc"
        + " OR licentie3hc = @lc OR licentie4hc = @lc OR licentie5hc = @lc OR licentie6hc = @lc OR licentie7hc = @LC OR licentie8hc = @lc"
        + " OR licentie9hc = @lc OR licentie10hc = @lc";
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", licenseid);
        IDCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lc", GetId);
```